# How do you timestamp a written document?

Tags: creative-writing, legal

How do you timestamp a written document? So that it can be used in a court of law if you seek to get compensation for a stolen intellectual property?

Comment: the answer might be relevant for you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48479/is-it-possible-to-make-a-proof-of-anteriority-for-sites-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those seeking compensation for intellectual property infringement, the United States court system [only accepts a single source of "timestamps"](https://www.mondaq.com/unitedstates/copyright/788820/us-supreme-court-holds-that-copyrights-must-be-registered-in-order-to-sue-for-infringement): the Copyright Office. [The registration process](https://www.copyright.gov/registration/) can cost as little as $35 dollars.

For more information see my answer to [Is emailing an original idea to oneself using Gmail a foolproof way to timestamp it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/56067/34330)